# Impact of not updating default AAM when changing from http to https

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, content, ssl, https

Usually when you first setup the SharePoint web app you do not have the SSL certificate. So, you setup the SharePoint web app using http:/foo.com

Later on you get the SSL, and update the bindings in IIS for the web application and add https:/foo.com

You then add https://foo.com to the AAM for the SharePoint web application.

Question:

1. What AAM level should you put the URL for HTTP and HTTPS? The default level already has http://foo.com.
2. Should you update the URL in the search content source from http://foo.com to https://foo.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Depend,how you want to access the site. If you want to user access the site using Https then you have to update the default URL /Public Url to https, Also you need another internal URL with http so that when user try to access the http://foo.com it will automatically redirect to the https://foo.com

from [this blog read the Issue #1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fabdulwahab/archive/2013/01/21/configure-ssl-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

For search, i think it auto update but if not you should change manually.

[AAM resource](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2013/05/25/alternate-access-mappings-explained.aspx)